# How do I reset an ESP8266 with an FTDI and no reset button?

Tags: esp8266, ftdi, reset

How do I reset an ESP8266 with an FTDI and no reset button? I assume that it has something to do with the reset pin on the ESP8266, but I cannot find a step-by-step usage of the pin online.

Comment: There is both a "reset" and a "program" pin on the ESP8266. You need both to reprogram it.

Comment: But how specifically do I reset it?

Comment: there are lots of different esp8266 boards, and several kinds of modules. Which one in particular?

Comment: also, are you asking how to do it under program control?

Comment: https://www.sparkfun.com/products/13678

Comment: No, just how to do it manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pull the reset pin up by connecting it to 3.3v with a 10k ohm resistor, then to reset the ESP you temporarily ground the pin, bringing it down to 0v/GND.
I'd recommend putting in a button for that :)